# AngularJS: Cursor is moving to last position when model is transformed

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am using zipcode directive which is accepting 9 digit US zip code and formatting it.

```
app.directive('formatZipCode', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
            function fromUser(text) {
                if (text) {
                    var transformedInput = text.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
                    if (transformedInput.length > 9) {
                        transformedInput = transformedInput.slice(0, 9);
                    }
                    if (transformedInput.length > 5) {
                        transformedInput = transformedInput.slice(0, 5) + "-" + transformedInput.slice(5);
                    }

                    if (transformedInput !== text) {
                        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                        ngModelCtrl.$render();
                    }
                    return transformedInput;
                }
                return undefined;
            }


            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(fromUser);
        }
    };
});
```

when I am removing any number from zipcode, cursor position moves back to last position.
[When I delete third number cursor moves to last number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxL4F.jpg)

How to retain the cursor position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this by using caret position. Remember the caret position and after formatting input assign the caret position again.

```
app.directive('formatZipCode', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
            function fromUser(text) {
                if (text) {
                    var transformedInput = text.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
                    if (transformedInput.length > 9) {
                        transformedInput = transformedInput.slice(0, 9);
                    }
                    var caretPosition = element[0].selectionStart || undefined;
                    if (transformedInput.length > 5) {                     
                        var realposition = caretPosition == 6 ? caretPosition + 1 : caretPosition;
                        transformedInput = transformedInput.slice(0, 5) + "-" + transformedInput.slice(5);
                    }

                    if (transformedInput !== text) {                      
                        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                        ngModelCtrl.$render();
                        if (typeof caretPosition === 'number') {
                            element[0].selectionStart = element[0].selectionEnd = realposition || caretPosition;
                        }
                        else {
                            element[0].selectionStart = element[0].selectionEnd = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    return transformedInput;
                }
                return undefined;
            }

            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(fromUser);
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to use [`ng-model-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions#!) to change when the input updates (and thus runs your formatter).

This is a case where you will sacrifice live reformatting in favor of form usability.

Either use

```
<input type="text" ng-model="zipcode" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" format-zip-code />
```

to update when the user leaves the field, or

```
<input type="text" ng-model="zipcode" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }" format-zip-code />
```

to update after `1s`.  This option will still show the cursor moving to the end of the input after the update, but not instantly.